# Joomla PHP how to programatically be taken to Edit Profile page

Tags: php, joomla

What is the best way to force users to the edit profile page.

Here is my code :

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->email === "fakemail@spam-disposable-domain.com") {
//Redirect user to the edit profile page forcing them to change their email.
//index.php?option=com_users&view=profile&layout=edit
}
```

I want to redirect users who's emails match that to force them to edit their profile the correct way to redirect them to the edit profile page is what I need to know.

Comment: split up the email by `@` and check against the domain? user `header()` to  send the user to the page?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript So a simple location redirect will do there is no redirect joomla function i should be using.....

Comment: I don't know the joomla framework but since it's php; `header("Location: path/to/page"); exit();` would still work

Comment: There should be something like `$app->redirect`. Try google.

Comment: @Xatenev Thanks for that information do you know if i need extra logic or if i will have issues saving the edit profile form with the redirect code when they change their email i am concerned it might not save due to the redirect logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `redirect()` method of the application object:

```
$app  = JFactory::getApplication();
$user = JFactory::getUser();

if ($user->email === "fakemail@spam-disposable-domain.com")
{
    $app->enqueueMessage('Please change your email address!');
    $app->redirect(
        JRoute::_(
            'index.php?option=com_users&view=profile&layout=edit'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nibra I shall mark it as answer when it lets me, May I also ask I am running this inside a custom plugin that executes on every single page view / load "public function onAfterInitialise() {" I want to know if this code will still let me save the edit profile form or if it will execute the redirect before the user can change their email.

Comment: On the profile page the code will produce a (endless) loop. You should not use it on the target URL.

Comment: Thank you @nibra I was able to mark your solution as the answer and I have just asked a new question posting the code as an example since I am having a infinite loop issue since I can't make the code only run when the user is not on the com_users component pages hopefully you can see what I have done wrong there.